# Passing parameters to Keytool from java swing using cmd

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I am trying to create a simple user interface for **keytool** to ease up the certificate generation process. I am aware that there are better ways to do this and creating a java swing interface is not the optimal solution.

I am getting the necessary parameters from swing components and pass it to the keytool as follow:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime
                    .getRuntime()
                    .exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"keytool.exe &"+command.toString()+" end\"");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now the problem is after passing the parameters nothing is happening and the cmd shows me the available options in keytool only.(same as entering **keytool** in cmd)

Here you can find the value of **command** String:

```
    command.append("keytool -genkey");//hardcoded for now, I'm using this method only
    command.append(" ");
    command.append("-keyalg");
    command.append(" ");
    command.append(algorithm.getSelectedItem()); //comboBox, value RSA/DSA/...
    command.append(" ");
    command.append("-alias");
    command.append(" ");
    command.append(alias.getText());//textfield value signedKey
    command.append(" ");
    command.append("-keystore");
    command.append(" ");
    command.append("selfsigned.jks");//hardcoded for now
    command.append(" ");
    command.append("-validity");
    command.append(" ");
    command.append(validity.getText());//textfield, value 365
    command.append(" ");
    command.append("-keysize");
    command.append(" ");
    command.append(keySize.getText());//depends on selected algorithm, values 2048/1024/...
```

I am new to keytool and for some reason I really cannot figure out what is wrong here, is it my approach or is it the parameters that I am passing...

P.S: sample of **command** String: `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias signedKey -keystore selfsigned.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048`

Comment: Build the complete command in a string first and print it before invoking it.  You'll see what's wrong

Comment: I forgot to add it in the question, thanks for the reminder :D

Comment: isn't you `keytool ' command repeated?

Comment: No, I mean the COMPLETE string you pass to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

Comment: this is the complete string: cmd /c start cmd.exe /K "keytool.exe &-genkey -keyalg RSA -alias signedKey -keystore selfsigned.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048 end"

Comment: oh... I forgot about the end... I feel dumb now

Comment: @JimGarrison is it possible to add another command for the keystore password part (and other parts like first name last name and so on)?

Comment: Just in case you don't know about it: keystore-explorer.org

Comment: @omikron haha I didn't know about! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the String I am using to pass parameter `cmd /c start cmd.exe /K "keytool.exe &-genkey -keyalg RSA -alias signedKey -keystore selfsigned.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048 end"`

The `end` makes the problem and once it s been removed it's all good.

Special thanks to Jim Garrison